# How can I implement step-by-step checkout process for my magento mobile theme?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, theme, mobile

I have two themes (mobile and desktop) in the same store view.
Desktop theme uses **onepage** checkout process . But however I want to **make** a **multi-step checkout process for the mobile theme** only.
i.e. the **browser has to load a new URL for each step**

i.e. when user comes to the checkout page and fill up the billing address and submit the button, the page will reload and take to the delivery address page..so on.

So can it be possible having **two types of checkout process in the same store view for two different theme** ?

If it is possible then how can I achieve this ? Please suggest some step by step guide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the following topic to help you designing a multistep checkout for your mobile theme: [Magento multi page checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43185/magento-multi-page-checkout)